# 外部からGoogle Apps Scriptを実行する方法

Tags: api, google-apps-script, oauth, google-cloud

### 前提

GCP や GAS に詳しい方、教えてください。

以下のサイトを参考にして Questetra 側の OAuth 機能を使い、
GAS の API を実行しようとしましたが、うまくいかず躓いております。
https://www.slideshare.net/miraclelinux/questetragoogle-apps-script

- Questetra 側
  　サイト内で指定された内容通りに設定しました
- GAS 側
  　以下がサイトとの相違点です

  - プロジェクトの関連付け
    クライアント ID とクライアントシークレット設定のため、スクリプトエディタで「リソース」を開いたところ、「Developers Console プロジェクト」はなく、「Cloud Platform プロジェクト」がありました。　
    関連付けされているプロジェクトがなかったため、 Google Cloud Platform のプロジェクト番号を入力し、関連付けさせました。
  - API の有効化
    API の検索窓に「Google Apps Script Execution API」が存在しなかったため、同名を検索して表示された「Apps Script API」を有効化しました。
  - OAuth2のクライアント ID
    承認済みのリダイレクト URI は、 Questetra では「https://f.questetra.net/oauth2callback」を入力するよう書かれていたため、こちらを設定しました。

---

### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

実行した結果、以下の通りエラーメッセージが Questetra へ返ってきました。

```
"error": {
"code": 401,
"message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
"status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
}
```

API を実行する方法について調べた結果、どこもほとんど同じ方法が記載されていました。
（どれも大体 2016 年に書かれたものでした）
エラーメッセージを調べても詳しい解決法がみつかりません。

わかる方いましたらご教示いただければと思います。
よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: @anya2110 さん、編集の提案をいただきましたが、質問主さんご自身のアカウントであれば自由に編集することができます。もし質問主さんと同一人物ということであれば、アカウントが 2 つに分かれてしまっているので[こちらのヘルプページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)を参考にアカウントを統合して頂けませんでしょうか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん、ご指摘ありがとうございます。先程アカウントの統合を行いました。